# Where or how do you ask for peer review?

Tags: publications

I have written a research report and did a literature review on specific topics, and I would like to know where I could ask for a peer review of my report. I'm new to this and would like to know if peer review is possible on literature review articles.

I would like to understand the whole process, and I would like to do this in a free and open-source way. I'm using Zenodo (European open-access publishing) and ResearchGate, publishing it as open-access and open-source.

If this has been asked before, please ignore my post and refer to those other posts where it's explained.

Edit: I have submitted my report on Zenodo to the Sustainable Engineering Science and Research Journal. I'm not sure if it's the correct community/journal to ask for a peer review. All I can do now is wait for a response.

Comment: What is your current position? Don’t you have a supervisor? If so they are the one to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: The conventional thing is: you attempt to publish in an established journal (or meeting), and the journal arranges for peer-review. Another would be: you apply for a job, and the prospective employer commissions the peer review.   I would be interested in answers here about formal peer-review outside these conventional venues.

Comment: Knowing what your field is would also be helpful. For example if it’s in life sciences or medicine you could look into eLife (https://elifesciences.org/), which reviews preprints.

Comment: @leonos I'm not studying at a research university but at a university of applied sciences (in Dutch: Hogeschool). You could compare this to a college and undergraduate study; I only did a literature review.

Comment: @RemziCavdar did you do the review as part of a course? In that case the lecturer (or equivalent) should be able to answer your questions. In general you’ll learn the most if you find a more experienced academic to collaborate with, especially for your first review.

Comment: @GEdgar I uploaded my article to zenodo.org, and it seems like I got a DOI link on Zenodo and can submit my articles to so-called communities. Still, many of these communities have different curation policies, and I can't seem to find the correct one for my topic.  I'm studying software engineering, but the subject I wrote this research report for is Professional Ethics and Social Orientation (PESO). PESO is more about the ethics of technology and whatnot.

Comment: @leonos Yes, I did this review as part of a course/subject. I was asked to do research about a certain topic, to look at the ethics of technology. I was able to come up with a topic and it was greenlit before writing my article. I got a good grade, a 9 comparable to an A. That';s why I published my report to Zenodo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Peer-review without special circumstances refers to the process of publishing an article in a journal or at a conference. The editors or organizers will then arrange for peer-review for some of the submitted papers. (Usually, there is a modus for desk-reject where the editor and head of the programming committee decides that a submission is clearly not worth publishing.)

There are more general understandings of the phrase "peer review". For example, a professor might assign papers submitted by students to other students to criticize. This is sometimes done in the education of future Ph.D.s.

The number of reviews is field dependent. In pure Mathematics, a single reviewer is often used, whereas in Computer Science, three reviewers is more often the target.

There are also outlets often on the web which have a somewhat lighter understanding of peer-review.

Depending on the field, literature reviews are often only published (and hence peer reviewed) by lower-quality outlets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And is peer review still possible in a non-traditional way, like self-publishing it or publishing it on an open collective or open access publisher like Zenodo and ResearchGate? Or is this an official process which can only happen when done with a traditional publisher?

Comment: “Peer-review without special circumstances refers to the process of publishing an article in a journal or at a conference.” I would say that’s inaccurate: these two things are not equivalent. You can get a preprint peer-reviewed without having it published, you can get a manuscript peer-reviewed without it being accepted in a specific journal, you can get an abstract accepted in a conference without formal peer-review.

Comment: @leonos Okay, I didn't know that. I should email organisations who are on Zenodo as a community. Or other individuals who might be interested or willing?

Comment: @RemziCavdar I’m not sure how Zenodo works, hopefully someone else on here will know better. I still think you should ask your lecturer / course manager for advice as they should know about journals or preprints specific to your field.

Comment: @leonos My school says you must do it yourself because they are not a research university (they are a: hogeschool - college). It's strange because some courses prepare you for a research university, like the course Research & Communication Skills, and at the end of the study, we're required to do a Bachelor's thesis. After two years, I'll be able to do a Master's at a research university, and next year, I can do a semester course there for preparation.

Comment: @leonos Yes, a peer can review a preprint or manuscript, but when people say "peer-review" that's not what they mean.

Comment: +1 overall, but your last sentence, _Depending on the field, literature reviews are often only published (and hence peer reviewed) by lower-quality outlets._ is not true for my field. Some higher impact journals mostly review-type articles (like https://www.cell.com/trends/ecology-evolution/home)

Comment: @RichardErickson It's hard to get these high profile reviews published as a student, though; they're mostly high impact because people want to read what top researchers in the field see as the state of the art and often include a component of establishing or making the case for broader conclusions than a single research paper can attempt.